Daylight Saving Time Changes Not Reflected in Application's Date and Time
Application below helps me to test change day light saving time. I change DLS flag with help of "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" button and system time changes. I see one hour changes in tray clock.

But application itself shows old time and variables isDaylightSaving value remains the same. If I do application restart it takes correct time.
But how to get correct time during DLS change without restarting?
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Label lblDateTime;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
    private TimeZoneInfo localTimeZone;

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialize the form and label
        this.Text = "Day Time Information";
        this.Width = 400;
        this.Height = 200;

        lblDateTime = new Label();
        lblDateTime.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16);
        lblDateTime.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 50);
        lblDateTime.AutoSize = true;
        this.Controls.Add(lblDateTime);

        // Get local time zone
        localTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;

        // Initialize the timer
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000; // Set interval to 1000 ms = 1 second
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start(); // Start the timer

        // Update the label immediately when form loads
        UpdateDateTime();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateDateTime(); // Update label every tick (1 second)
    }

    private void UpdateDateTime()
    {
        // Get current UTC time
        DateTimeOffset utcNow = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        // Calculate the local time by applying the local time zone offset, considering DST
        DateTimeOffset localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcNow, localTimeZone);

        // Check if the time is currently in Daylight Saving Time in the local time zone
        bool isDaylightSaving = localTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(localTime);

        // Display the local time with DST status
        lblDateTime.Text = $"{localTime:dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt} (DST: {isDaylightSaving})";
    }

}


Does DateTimeOffset.Now return the correct value, or does that also need an app restart?

@AndrewMorton it returns incorrect value and needs app restart

Have you tried using TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()?

As an aside, it would have been easier to reproduce this with a short but complete console application - just prompt users to hit return to log a new "current time".

You need to call TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData().
Here's a simple app to test it:
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press return to log the current time");
    Console.ReadLine();
    TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
    var localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
    DateTimeOffset utcNow = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    DateTimeOffset localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcNow, localZone);
    Console.WriteLine($"{localTime:dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt} (DST: {localZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(utcNow)})");
}

Without the call to TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData(), changing the control panel setting has no effect on the app. With the call, the change is reflected in the app's output.

You can get the status of the "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" button immediately by reading from the registry, something like this:
private void UpdateDateTime()
{
    // Get current UTC time
    DateTimeOffset utcNow = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    // Calculate the local time by applying the local time zone offset, considering DST
    DateTimeOffset localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcNow, localTimeZone);

    // Check if the time is currently in Daylight Saving Time in the local time zone
    bool isDaylightSaving = localTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(localTime);

    var autoDstEnabled = !Convert.ToBoolean(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\TimeZoneInformation", "DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled", true));

    if (autoDstEnabled)
    {
        var offset = (Int32)Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\TimeZoneInformation", "ActiveTimeBias", 0);
        localTime = localTime.AddMinutes(offset);
    }

    // Display the local time with DST status
    lblDateTime.Text = $"{localTime:dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt} (DST: {isDaylightSaving})";
}


This seems unnecessary to me and requires registry access which makes it less portable. All the OP needs to do is clear the cached data.
